# Remove Different Texts When EVEN pace not notepad

Tags: notepad

excuse my English.
How do I remove at once the texts located within the divs?

example:

```html
line1 - <div id = "test"> 12345 </ div>
line2 - <div id = "test"> 23564 </ div>
line3 - <div id = "test"> ABCFDS </ div>
line4 - <div id = "test"> CDFGH </ div>
line5 - <div id = "test"> 12S4G </ div>
```

Must be like this:

```html
line1 - <div id = "test"> </ div>
line2 - <div id = "test"> </ div>
line3 - <div id = "test"> </ div>
line4 - <div id = "test"> </ div>
line5 - <div id = "test"> </ div>
```

How I do this by using the regular expression in notepad?

Answer (score 0):

**Find** : `(<\s*div[^>]*>).*?(<\s*/\s*div\s*>)`

**Replace** : `\1\2`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tV4eO5/1)